# Getting null pointer exception in generic runner class in cucmber+testng framework for aws device farm

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, appium-android, aws-device-farm

I am working on cucmber + testng framework to open the browser in mobile in device farm but unable to open through cucmber framework.I am getting null pointer exception in generic runner class at tear down last line.

```
public class LoginTest  extends TestBase{


    AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    private final String URL_STRING = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";

    @Given("I navigate to the login page")
    public void i_navigate_to_the_login_page() throws MalformedURLException {
         URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url, new DesiredCapabilities());
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    @When("click on x button")
    public void click_on_x_button() {
       }

@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/feature"},
     glue={"stepDef"},
    tags = {"~@Ignore"}

    )
```

```
public class GenericRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests   {

        private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

        @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
            testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        }

        @Test
        public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
            testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
        }

        @DataProvider
        public Object[][] features() {
            return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
        }

        @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
            TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner=new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
            testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: i am getting this exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.reporter(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lgherkin/formatter/Reporter;

Comment: You said you were getting a null pointer exception. A "NoSuchMethodError" is not the same thing. Which are you getting then?

Comment: Are you using the standard or custom environment? Does error happen locally? Try custom environment if not already done.

Comment: Could you please post the full StackTrace? And which version of Cucumber are you using?

Comment: this is fixed now .Solution is to get right structure for testng+cucmber framework for aws device farm